# Scraping text within a nested div using Rvest

Tags: web-scraping, rvest

I tried to scrape "Hello" from class d using purely rvest in R. May I know how could I achieve it?

```
<div class="a"> 
   <div data-bv-show="inline" ...> 
     <div> 
         <div id="3488282992992c" class="b"> 
            <div class="c"> </div> 
            <div class="d" > Hello </div> 
         </div> 
     </div> 
   </div> 
</div>
```

First, I tried `.....html.element(".d")` but it returns nothing. The same with `.....html.elements(".a div[data-bv-show=inline] .b .d")` in the second attempt. Any ideas on how it works?

Comment: `html_elements(.d) %>% html_text()` should work

Comment: it does work. i just got one na returned. is this because of the class "data-bv-show"?

Comment: If you could provide a link it would be helpful.